# How to make netlib-java use the native Intel MKL library LAPACK implementation?

Tags: java, windows, lapack, intel-mkl, netlib

I'm using [netlib-java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java) via [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) and upon initialization I see that netlib is linking to the reference lapack library implementations which AFAIK are not optimized. However, I have Intel MKL latest version installed in my Windows 7 64b machine and would like netlib-java to link to the Intel MKL native LAPACK library dll's.

What do I have to do to link netlib-java to use the Intel MKL LAPACK implementation?